# How to write query to generate XML file from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, xml, sql-server-2008

Hi please tell me how to generate XML file from Table in SQL Server using Query.
My Query is,

```
 select JobTitle as title,PostedDate as date from Jobs
```

C# code,

```
 protected void btnXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet dsJobsDetails = new DataSet();
                dsJobsDetails = GetJobDetails();
                string fileLoc = @"C:\JobDocuments\jobsxml.xml";
                FileStream fs = null;
                fs = File.Create(fileLoc);
                fs.Close();
                if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
                {
                    dsJobsDetails.WriteXml(fileLoc);
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }


private DataSet GetJobDetails()
        {
            DataSet ds = null;
            SQLProvider provider = new SQLProvider();
            SqlParameter[] paramCandidate = new SqlParameter[2];

            try
            {
                paramCandidate[0] = provider.MakeParameter("JobID", SqlDbType.VarChar, "0");
                paramCandidate[1] = provider.MakeParameter("AccountID", SqlDbType.Int, "0");
                ds = provider.RunProcedure("Usp_GetJobsDetailsForXML", paramCandidate);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SetLastError(ex);
                paramCandidate = null;
                provider = null;
                ds = null;
            }
            finally
            {
                paramCandidate = null;
                provider = null;
            }
            return ds;
        }
```

My stored procedure is,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_GetJobsDetailsForXML]          
(                                   
    @JobID varchar(8000),  
    @AccountID int              
)                                  
AS                              

BEGIN                                                                   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;                                        
     select JobTitle as title,PostedDate as date,JobDescription as [description] from Jobs 
     where JobID in (@JobID)   
     --FOR XML PATH('Jobs')                                                   
END
```

It is giving output as follows,

```
 <NewDataSet>
    <Table>
      <title>DBA</title> 
      <date>2014-09-30</date> 
      </Table>
     <Table>
      <title>Manager</title> 
      <date>2014-09-30</date>
     </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
```

Here i want to add Root node as jobs and sub root node as job. I tried 
`select JobTitle as title,PostedDate as date from Jobs  FOR XML PATH('jobs')` it is not working.
I want output as follows,

```
<jobs>
<job>
<title>
<![CDATA[ DBA ]]>
</title>
<date>
<![CDATA[ 2014-09-30 ]]>
</date>
</job>
<job>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Manager ]]>
</title>
<date>
<![CDATA[ 2014-09-30 ]]>
</date>
</job>
<jobs>
```

Thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
    SELECT '<![CDATA[' + JobTitle + ']]>' as title,
       '<![CDATA[' + PostedDate + ']]>'  as date,
       '<![CDATA[' + JobDescription + ']]>' as [description] 
FROM Jobs 
     WHERE JobID in (@JobID)   
     FOR XML PATH('Job'), ROOT('JOBS')
```

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek, i tried your code..It is giving output like this.. - <NewDataSet>
- <Table>
  <XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B><jobs><job>....></jobs></XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B> 
  </Table>
  </NewDataSet>

Comment: Hi 1612, Its quite difficult to generate the whole code, my approach in this case will be: from stored procedure I will return the 'xml' and on c# code I will opt for string rather than dataset. And will simply apply linq to get <Jobs>  element before writing to xml file. LinQ like 'var result = xmldoc.Element("Jobs"))'......... will do the job elimanating elements like '</XML_F52E2B61-‌​18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B> </Table> </NewDataSet>'.

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek , If i remove ' FOR XML PATH('Job'), ROOT('JOBS') ' from query its working. But i am getting <Table> Node.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataSet dst = new DataSet("Jobs");
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Job");

        DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("Title");
        DataColumn c2 = new DataColumn("Date");
        table.Columns.Add(c1);
        table.Columns.Add(c2);

        DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
        row1["Title"] = "T1";
        row1["Date"] = "D1";

        DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
        row2["Title"] = "T2";
        row2["Date"] = "D2";

        table.Rows.Add(row1);
        table.Rows.Add(row2);

        dst.Tables.Add(table);

        string p = dst.GetXml();
```

Here is example what you need to do. In your case when you fetch the data from database in method `GetJobDetails`, you should return `DataSet`, with `DataSetName = "Jobs"` and the defaultTableName of the `DataTable` should be Job !

You are not showing the method which fetch the data from database because of the I write you this example !

**Edit:**

First in `btnXML_Click` write it like this:

```
DataSet dsJobsDetails = GetJobDetails();
```

instead of

```
DataSet dsJobsDetails = new DataSet();
dsJobsDetails = GetJobDetails();
```

In `private DataSet GetJobDetails()` write it like this:

DataSet ds = new DataSet("Jobs");

instead of:

```
DataSet ds = null;
```

IN `SQLProvider` class you should add property TableName and when DataSqlAdapter.Fill the query like this:

```
 using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
 {
     adapter.Fill(resultDst, TableName);
 }
```

You need to set the property `TableName` value to `Job`

Comment: @1612 I hope you are using SqlDataAdapter.Fill method to return dataSet ?

Comment: @1612 I can not be more specific hope it helps you.